# MySQL: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'Category object' for column 'category_id' at row 1")

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

Using MySQL with Django, I have changed a model from using strings for "category" to using a FK. It is now broken with

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'Category object' for column 'category_id' at row 1")
```

Initially, it looked like:

```
class ItemRecord(models.Model):
    catalog_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # is the item being sold at all? (carried)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True) # is the item currently in stock?
    banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class FermentableRecord(ItemRecord):#record of each item
    pass

class HopRecord(ItemRecord):
    pass

class YeastRecord(ItemRecord):
    pass
```

Then, I use FK:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class ItemRecord(models.Model):
    catalog_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # is the item being sold at all? (carried)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True) # is the item currently in stock?
    banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="items")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class FermentableRecord(ItemRecord):#record of each item
    pass

class HopRecord(ItemRecord):
    pass

class YeastRecord(ItemRecord):
    pass
```

This broke from using the same related name on 3 different Record models.
Next I had:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class ItemRecord(models.Model):
    catalog_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # is the item being sold at all? (carried)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True) # is the item currently in stock?
    banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class FermentableRecord(ItemRecord):#record of each item
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="fermentable_items", null=True, blank=True)

class HopRecord(ItemRecord):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="hops_items", null=True, blank=True)

class YeastRecord(ItemRecord):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="yeast_items", null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I have:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class ItemRecord(models.Model):
    catalog_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # is the item being sold at all? (carried)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True) # is the item currently in stock?
    banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class FermentableRecord(ItemRecord):#record of each item
    pass

class HopRecord(ItemRecord):
    pass

class YeastRecord(ItemRecord):
    pass
```

I can `makemigrations`, but I cannot even connect to db at all. I want to just reset the db since it's in development, but I can't do anything. The `category` field was a string, then I set it to FK which expects an int before clearing the existing string values (which where all 'Category object' due to a mistake).

Comment: "but I cannot even connect to db at all." please explain this. How can you migrate if you can't connect to the database?

Comment: it won't migrate, I meant it only makemigrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is remove the data in category, you can do the following in your shell:

```
$ python manage.py dbshell # this will start the mysql client
mysql> show tables likes '%_itemrecord'; -- find the table name
mysql> update XXX_itemrecord set category=null; -- this will set all category values to NULL so that you can migrate to FK
```

If you don’t mind losing your data, and your application name is app_name, you can do the following in your shell:

```
$ python manage.py migrate app_name zero # this will blow away all your current data
$ python manage.py migrate app_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check that **category object** exists in **Category** table with id stored initially in category field.

For example: Category objects exists for id = 1366

```
Category.objects.filter(id=1366).exists()
```